# Comparing char* in C

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am trying to compare patterns of bits, to do this I have a struct which holds a pattern as a string. I then want compare that string to another string I built. I am using strcmp, however it is matching two strings even though they do not match. 
This is my code

```
typedef struct
{
    int emp;
    char *context;
    int numOnes;
    int numZeros;


}Pattern;

char *patt, str[t+1];
    patt = str;
    while(count<t){
        //printf("Stream: %d\n", stream[end]);
        if(stream[end] == 1){
            patt[count]= '1';
            //writeBit(1);
        }
        else{
            patt[count]='0';
            //writeBit(0);
        }


        end--;
        count++;
    } //code to build a string

while(i<(1<<t)&&(found==0)){
        if((strcmp(patt,patterns[i].context)==0)){
            if(patterns[i].numOnes <= patterns[i].numZeros){
                prediction = 0;
                checkPredict(prediction,stream[end], i);
            }
            else{
                prediction = 1;
                checkPredict(prediction,stream[end], i);
            }
            found = 1;

        }
        else{
            found = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }//comparing string
```

Comment: `I am using strcmp, however it is matching two strings even though they do not match.` how you identifying it? have you debug it? debug by printing values.

Answer (score 3):

You never terminate `patt`, i.e. write the `'\0'` character after the last character. Thus, it's not a valid string so you can't use `strcmp()` on it.

Comment: strcmp **requires** a null-terminated string, at least in most implementations. See the [implementation by Apple](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c), which should be similar to the one used in BSDs.

Comment: @no92 Isn't that what I just said? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong. I'm only adding that it is required. Also note that `gcc` is adding it automatically when needed (and possible), so your answer may be pointless if he's using only `char *` for strings.

Comment: @no92 I read the code in the question, I know that `patt` is a non-terminated string when he calls `strcmp()` on it. That's what my answer says. I agree that the code itself is quite confusing too, but those parts seems clear.